# Constructing a Hypergeometric Function

Tags: hypergeometric-function, pochhammer-symbol

I am asked to find values for $a,b$ and $c$ such that $$ \frac{1}{2} ((1+x)^{2\alpha}-(1-x)^{2\alpha}) = 2\alpha x\ _2F_1(a,b;c;x^2)$$

I have attempted the following: 
$$\frac{1}{2} ((1+x)^{2\alpha}-(1-x)^{2\alpha}) = \frac{1}{2}\sum^{\infty}_{k=0}\binom{2\alpha}{k}x^k-\sum^{\infty}_{k=0}\binom{2\alpha}{k}(-x)^k \\ = \frac{1}{2} \sum^{\infty}_{k=0}\binom{2\alpha}{k}(x^k-(-x)^k). $$

My lecturer then advised that I should try to rewrite the binomial as Pochammer Symbols which led me to:
$$\frac{1}{2}\sum^{\infty}_{k=0}\frac{(2\alpha -k +1)_k}{k!}(x^k-(-x)^k)$$

We can also see here that for values $k= 2n$ we will recieve a term equal to 0, hence we can rewrite our equation as:

$$\frac{1}{2}\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\frac{(2\alpha -(2n+1) +1)_{(2n+1)}}{(2n+1)!}(x^{(2n+1)}-(-x)^{(2n+1)})$$

We simpify to:

$$x\frac{1}{2}\sum^{\infty}_{n=0}\frac{(2\alpha-2n)_{(2n+1)}}{(2n+1)!}(x^{2n}-(-x)^{2n})$$

Now at this point I'm not really sure where to go... I feel like I'm really close and not seeing something or maybe really far away and not aware! 
Either way any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the expansion
\begin{align}
f(x)&=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{k=0}^\infty \binom{2\alpha}{k}\left( x^k-(-x)^k \right)\\
&=x\sum_{n=0}^\infty \binom{2\alpha}{2n+1}x^{2n}\\
&=x\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_nX^{n}
\end{align}
with $X=x^2$, the ratio of two successive terms of the series  is
\begin{align}
\frac{c_{n+1}}{c_n}\frac{X^{n+1}}{X^n}&=\frac{\binom{2\alpha}{2n+3}}{\binom{2\alpha}{2n+1}}X\\
&=\frac{(n-\alpha+1/2)(n-\alpha+1)}{(n+3/2)}\frac{X}{n+1}
\end{align}
then, with $a_1=\frac{1}{2}-\alpha$, $ a_2=1-\alpha$ and $ b_1=\frac{3}{2}$ and with $c_0=\binom{2\alpha}{1}=2\alpha$, it gives
\begin{align}
f(x)&=2\alpha x\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(a_1)_n(a_2)_n}{(b_1)_n}\frac{X^n}{n!} \\
&=2\alpha x \ _2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2}-\alpha,1-\alpha;\frac{3}{2};x^2  \right)
\end{align}

Comment: Apologies if this is trivial, but what exactly did you do when you converted the binomial to $c_n$ and $X^n$ ; and then what lead you to look at the ratio of two successive terms?

Comment: Not a problem. I think the simplest way is to convert the binomial into products and ratio of $\Gamma$ functions to simplify the ratio of the coefficients. Then, this ratio is a rational function of $n$ which factors can easily be identified as a ratio of Pochhammer symbols.

Comment: Sorry for the typos

Comment: No worries! I'm still trying to learn the manipulations in the ratio of the two successive terms and keep hitting a wall, if I update my question with my attempt so far could you possibly tell me where I am going wrong?

Comment: The ratio of two successive terms in the series expressed as in the penultimate equation is$$\frac{c_{n+1}X^{n+1}}{c_nX^n}=\frac{(a_1+n)(a_2+n)}{b_1+n}\frac X{n+1}$$We can thus identify $a_1,a_2,b_1$.

Comment: Thank you it's all starting to come together now :) Just one last question, why is it we remove the term $c_0$ to outside the summation, and also as we do that why do we still begin the summation at $n=0$ ?

Comment: The first term ($n=0$) must be $c_0$, then this factor remains as the only condition we imposed was on the successive ratios: $c_1/c_0$, $c_2/c_1\ldots$.

Answer (score 0):

Using Maple I looked at the Maclaurin series of the difference of the two sides to order $x^{20}$, and solved with Groebner basis methods.  It found $15$ solution families:
$$ \matrix{\alpha = 0, \; a,b,c\ \text{arbitrary} \cr
\alpha = -1,\; a=0, \; b,c\ \text{arbitrary} \cr
\alpha = -1,\; b=0, \; a,c\ \text{arbitrary}\cr 
\alpha = -1,\; b=2,\; a=c,\; c \ \text{arbitrary}\cr
\alpha = -1,\; b=c,\; a=2,\; c \ \text{arbitrary}\cr
\alpha = 3/2,\; b=-1,\; a=-c/3,\; c \ \text{arbitrary}\cr
\alpha = 3/2,\; b=-c/3,\; a=-1,\; c \ \text{arbitrary}\cr
\alpha = 1/2,\; a=0, \; b,c\ \text{arbitrary}\cr
\alpha = 1/2,\; b=0, \; a,c\ \text{arbitrary}\cr
\alpha = -1/2,\; b = 1, \; a=c,\; c \ \text{arbitrary}\cr
\alpha = -1/2,\; a = 1, \; b=c,\; c \ \text{arbitrary}\cr
\alpha = 2,\; b=-1,\; a=-c,\; c \ \text{arbitrary}\cr
\alpha = 2,\; a=-1,\; b=-c,\; c \ \text{arbitrary}\cr
a = 1/2 - \alpha, \; b = 1-\alpha,\; c = 3/2,\; \alpha \ \text{arbitrary}\cr
a = 1-\alpha,\; b = 1/2-\alpha,\;  c = 3/2,\; \alpha \ \text{arbitrary}\cr } 
$$
Maple confirms that each of these works.